# modal mask not masking the entire window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement modal window on my page. Idea is to display a popup window with project screen shot and code sample. For now I've implemented popup window with screen shot. Seems to work fine except having 2 issues.

1) mask is not covering the entire window.
2) once popup window is closed, without refreshing if I click the screen shot again, mask is not displayed.

[webpage](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/projects.html)

```
<div class="screenshot">
            <div class="case">
                <div class="thumb"> <a id="hooversMobile" href="#dialog" name="modal" title="Hoover's Mobile Site"><img src="images/proj_over_2.png" alt="Project thumbnail" style="top: 0px; "></a>
                </div><!-- end thumb-->
            </div><!-- end case-->
        </div>
```

[.js](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/js/projects.js)

Comment: 1) mask is not covering the entire window. 2) once popup window is closed, without refreshing if I click the screen shot again, mask is not displayed.

Comment: those are **not** questions! just facts about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following DIV has position relative set.  This means any position: absolute elements below it will be relative to its position.

```
<div class="project" id="mobile"></div>
```

This is what is causing the overlay to only extend from that position.

The second click problem is due to #mask being faded out but not running fadeIn again like you do on the content div.

Also, to get a better response you should pick out part of the code and copy into JSfiddle.  Then you can ask very specific questions about the overlay positioning.

Comment: I tried replicating the code..but works fine in jsfiddle. I kinda fixed the mask click issue(fade in/ fade out) but still mask is covering the enitre window

Comment: Once you remove position: relative from #wrapper and #project.  Then add top: 0px; and left: 0px; to #mask you should see it go full screen.

Comment: Think you could give the change a try on the site so i can take a look?